# Organizer does not receive email notification when attendee declines the event

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

We use a service account to authenticate google calendar and programmatically create calendars and appointment events. However, when a customer declines an event, there's no notification whatsoever of the decline and we cannot find any email regarding the decline in the admin or organizer's email inbox. is it because the service account is a dummy user? How can we get the organizer to be tied to an actual email account so people can get notification of the response status of the attendee?

We tried

1. create the calendar and event programmatically, attendee declines, no notification (despite `setSendNotification("all")` in the API call)
2. create the calendar and event programmatically, move the organizer to a different calendar (new organizer), attendee declines, no notification for the new organizer (despite `setSendNotification("all")` in the API call)

update code

```
googleAPIHelper.executeWithThrottling(service.events().update(calendarId, remoteEvent.getId(), remoteEvent).setSendUpdates("all"), Event.class);
```

insert code

```
googleAPIHelper.executeWithThrottling(service.events().insert(calendarId, eventToInsert).setSendUpdates("all"), Event.class);
```

move organizer code

```
googleAPIHelper.executeWithThrottling(service.events().move(calendarId, remoteEvent.getId(), destinationCalendarId), Event.class);
```

Comment: Can you please provide the whole code you are working on?

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, for each calendar the organizer owns (found in "Other Calendars"), we have to toggle the "Other notifications" settings to receive an email (i.e. Event responses). The default is set to "None."

E.g. [image: Other calendars > Other notifications > default is "None" and need to toggle to "Email"]

See also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgbpsm82AaY